# html/css grid match content width for each column

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my grid items to line up so if I have items that are longer then other items, they stretch the div of all the other items. This is what is happening, and the snip-it below is what I would want to happen.

Anyone have any ideas?

```css
#grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: fit-content(100%) [start] auto fit-content(100%) [end] fit-content(100%) [end] fit-content(100%) [end] fit-content(100%) [end] fit-content(100%) [end] fit-content(100%) [end];
}

.cat,
.title,
.icon,
.date {
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid-container">
  <div class="cat">accusamus</div>
  <div class="title">
    <a class="titleURL" href="">Lorem ipsum</a>
  </div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="date">22/Sep/2017</div>
  <div>143</div>
  <div>490</div>
  <div>323</div>
  <div class="user">username5362</div>
</div>
<div id="grid-container">
  <div class="cat">Bo</div>
  <div class="title">
    <a class="titleURL" href="">qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor</a>
  </div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="date">08/Nov/2014</div>
  <div>1543</div>
  <div>4790</div>
  <div>3223</div>
  <div class="user">aker009</div>
</div>
```

This is what I want to happen, except not have everything lumped into a single div.

```css
#grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: fit-content(100%) [start] auto fit-content(100%) [end] fit-content(100%) [end] fit-content(100%) [end] fit-content(100%) [end] fit-content(100%) [end] fit-content(100%) [end];
}

.cat,
.title,
.icon,
.date {
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid-container">
  <div class="cat">accusamus</div>
  <div class="title">
    <a class="titleURL" href="">Lorem ipsum</a>
  </div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="date">22/Sep/2017</div>
  <div>143</div>
  <div>490</div>
  <div>323</div>
  <div class="user">username5362</div>
  <div class="cat">Bo</div>
  <div class="title">
    <a class="titleURL" href="">qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor</a>
  </div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="date">08/Nov/2014</div>
  <div>1543</div>
  <div>4790</div>
  <div>3223</div>
  <div class="user">aker009</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use a grid system, check out the flexbox link I posted at the bottom. Otherwise bootstrap is a great framework for responsive layout as well.

Believe this will do what you are looking for:

```
<table id="gridContainer">
  <tr>
    <td class="cat">
      accusamus
    </td>
    <td class="title">
      <a class="titleURL" href="">Lorem ipsum</a>
    </td>
    <td class="icon">
      <p class="date">22/Sep/2017</p>
    </td>
    <td class="date">
      <p>143</p>
      <p>490</p>
      <p>323</p>
    </td>
    <td class="user">
      username5362
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cat">
      Bo
    </td>
    <td class="title">
      <a class="titleURL" href="">qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor</a>
    </td>
    <td class="icon">
      <div class="date">08/Nov/2014</div>
    </td>
    <td class="date">
      <p>1543</p>
      <p>4790</p>
      <p>3223</p>
    </td>
    <td class="user">
      aker009
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's the css:

```
.cat,
.title,
.icon,
.date {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  padding-right:15px !important;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}

.date p {
  display: inline-block;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

tr, td {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

Using a simple table is easier than trying to force the container. Alternatively, I would look into using "flexbox" It allows for more responsive design, and is kind of what you were attempting to do. Also worth nothing, you really do not want to use an "id" more than one time on a given page. If you need to use it more than once, you should use a class.

here's some more information about [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Mastering_Wrapping_of_Flex_Items)

and here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/chris-hitchcock/pen/JBbJvq)

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the width of your grid column is according to the content, I think defining min-width and max-width for every column can help but you need to manage the text-overflow as well while defining max-width for the columns.